# Where was the lagoon gate in Jurassic World?

Tags: jurassic-world, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

In *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom*, we see the Mosasaurus escape from the lagoon and into the ocean through a gate. In *Jurassic World*, however, there is no gate to be seen during any of the lagoon shots and on the maps of Isla Nublar we can see that the Lagoon is in the center of the island.

How did the Mosasaurus get through the gate since it seemingly did not exist anytime before the movie? In-universe answers only, please.

Comment: I've tried to make the title a bit more descriptive and in-line with the question being asked in the body

Comment: I am voting to delete this question

Comment: On what grounds? It's a decent question and answerable, albeit not in-universe.

Comment: Where was the lagoon gate in Jurassic World? Right at the front of the lagoon.

Comment: In camp cretaceous it's revealed that there are underground streams and rivers differentiating in size (also home to the genetically modified bioluminecent parasaurophus)throughout isla nublar, one of them does lead into the lagoon however it is most likely in accessible heading upstream and much too small for the mosasoar it is possible however there is one heading south from the lagoon, maybe as some sort of contingency plan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no *in-universe* explanation. The filmmakers simply moved the lagoon a few miles (in the sequel) so that they could have a gate, which they also added, that leads out of the lagoon and to the outside ocean.

**Before (Jurassic world)**
[image]

**After (Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom)**
[image]

Interestingly, the director Colin Trevorrow claims that this was an error by the VFX team (with the map seen on screen) and that the gate was supposed to lead to a series of unseen canals that would allow access to the ocean, allowing the lagoon to remain central on the island.

> The lagoon is in the center of the island, connected to the ocean by a canal system. The digital maps in the film are incorrect, not a retcon. My fault for missing it, I had no idea the change was made until it was too late. Hope you guys can forgive it.
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/colintrevorrow/status/1008658304841723906?lang=en)</sup></sub>

And other digital maps from the same design team (admittedly [designed for the viral website](https://twitter.com/mbejaranoweb/status/1013854538288254977) rather than the film) have it back in its original place.

[image]

Comment: "Hope you guys can forgive it" — sure, Colin. Movie fans on Twitter are famously reasonable and well-balanced.